Reducing fractions in $\Bbb Q[(1+\sqrt{D})/2]$
I am reading the proof of $\mathbb{Z}[(1+\sqrt{-19})/2]$ being a PID in Dummit&Foote's Abstract Algebra on p.282. The authors use the Dedekind-Hasse norm $N$, which is positive and for any $a,b\in R-\{0\}$, either $a\in(b)$ or $\exists\,r\in(a,b)$ s.t. $N(r)<N(b)$.
It says that:"Write $\frac{\alpha}{\beta}=\frac{a+b\sqrt{-19}}{c}\in\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{-19}]$ with integers $a,b,c$ having no common divisor and with $c>1$ (since $\beta$ is assumed not to be divide $\alpha$)."
But I can not realize the connection between "$\frac{\alpha}{\beta}=\frac{a+b\sqrt{-19}}{c}\in\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{-19}]-\mathbb{Z}[(1+\sqrt{-19})/2]$" and "with integers $a,b,c$ having no common divisor and with $c>1$". I can just conclude that at least one of $a/c$ or $b/c$ is in $\frac12\mathbb{Z}$ by solving the equations:
$$
\begin{aligned}
 \frac{a+b\sqrt{-19}}{c}&=x+y\frac{1+\sqrt{-19}}{2}
    \\
    \Rightarrow\ \ &\begin{cases}
        \frac ac=x+\frac y2
        \\\frac bc=\frac y2
    \end{cases}
\end{aligned}
$$

Closely related to OP's prior question. $\ \ $

Rationalize the denom of $,\frac{\alpha}{\beta},$ to get $,\frac{a+b\sqrt{-19}}c,,$ then cancel $,\gcd(a,b.c),$ from top & bottom. Since $,\frac{\alpha}{\beta}\not\in\Bbb Z[(1+\sqrt{-19}],$ the resulting reduced denom $,\bar c,$ can't be $,\pm 1.\ \ $

@BillDubuque Thanks for your idea. In your method, denominator-rationalizing and fraction-reducing are to make sure $\frac{a+b\sqrt{-19}}{c}$ be in lowest terms. But I think the form $\frac{a+b\sqrt{-19}}{c}$ is just to ensure $\alpha/\beta\in\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{19})$, and I think $c\ne\pm1$ just can provide that $\alpha/\beta\not\in\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-19}]$, where $\mathbb{Z}[(1+\sqrt{-19})/2]$ is a larger set than $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-19}]$. To make sure that $\alpha/\beta\not\in\mathbb{Z}[(1+\sqrt{-19})/2]$, should we consider other restrictions? Like what I have shown in my question.

Did you try an actual example instead of trying to deal with the most general case symbolically? If you do then I think it is much easier to see what is going on: just rationalize the denominators of the coefficients of $1$ and $\sqrt{-19}$, then use a positive common denominator so you have $\alpha/\beta = a/c + (b/c)\sqrt{-19}$, and then divide $a$, $b$, and $c$ by $\gcd(a,b,c)$ so we are in the situation where $\gcd(a,b,c) = 1$. We can't have $c = 1$ since $\alpha/\beta$ is not in $\mathbf Z[\sqrt{-19}]$, so $c > 1$.
Update: Since $\mathbf Z[(1+\sqrt{-19})/2] = \{(m+n\sqrt{-19})/2 : m \equiv n \bmod 2\}$, the number $a/c + (b/c)\sqrt{-19}$ with $\gcd(a,b,c) = 1$ and $c \geq 1$ is in $\mathbf Z[(1+\sqrt{-19})/2]$ if and only if (i) $c=1$ or (ii) $c=2$ and $a, b$ are odd. Thus $a/c + (b/c)\sqrt{-19}$ with $\gcd(a,b,c) = 1$ and $c \geq 1$ is not in $\mathbf Z[(1+\sqrt{-19})/2]$ if and only if (i) $c=2$ and $a \not\equiv b \bmod 2$ or (ii) $c > 2$.

Thanks for your idea. In your method, denominator-rationalizing and fraction-reducing are to make sure $\frac{a+b\sqrt{-19}}{c}$ be in lowest terms. But I think the form $\frac{a+b\sqrt{-19}}{c}$ is just to ensure $\alpha/\beta\in\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{19})$, and I think $c\ne\pm1$ just can provide that $\alpha/\beta\not\in\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-19}]$, where $\mathbb{Z}[(1+\sqrt{-19})/2]$ is a larger set than $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-19}]$. To make sure that $\alpha/\beta\not\in\mathbb{Z}[(1+\sqrt{-19})/2]$, should we consider other restrictions? Like what I have shown in my question.

I added a 2nd paragraph.

Thanks for your providing a equivalent definition: $\mathbb{Z}[(1+\sqrt{-19})/2] = {(m+n\sqrt{-19})/2 : m \equiv n \bmod 2}$, it does help to me. Wish you a nice day!
